# Cobratoolbox unable to identify gurobi solver when passing initCobraToolbox

Tags: matlab

I am running into this issue lately when I am trying to install the Cobratoolbox on matlab along with having installed the prerequisite gurobi solver and adding it to the MATLAB path. I have run the gurobi_setup.m file as well. However I am unable to uninstall the cobratoolbox, as everytime i run initCobraToolbox.m it fails as it not able to recognize the solver. Is there anything I am missing in the installation? I have attached a screenshot for reference[image]

Comment: In my opinion it is better to redirect the question to cobra-toolbox google group https://groups.google.com/g/cobra-toolbox

Comment: Not that I would know this package, but Installation should be clear in the README file and if you run into troubles while following it, it's good enough to open an issue on the platform where they develop the package. Not that I would think this question does not belong here, but I think you have much better chances there.